tinymce continously showing me a parse error
I have a tinymce code and I even tried setTimeout and init_callback also to check if the editor is loading properly or not
it does not seems to be bring in the data, i am continuously getting an error
tinymce.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parse')
    at tinymce.min.js:4:230108
    at tinymce.min.js:4:230230
    at I.map (tinymce.min.js:4:2258)
    at tinymce.min.js:4:229452
    at Object.setContent (tinymce.min.js:4:230293)
    at tinymce.min.js:4:244007
    at tinymce.min.js:4:244023
    at Object.map (tinymce.min.js:4:83880)
    at bw (tinymce.min.js:4:243967)
    at vB.setContent (tinymce.min.js:4:427144)

my JS COde
var textareaId = `editor_${languageTypes[language].type}_${field.name}`;
        $('<textarea>').attr({
          id: textareaId,
          name: `${languageTypes[language].type}_${field.name}`,
          rows: 4,
          class: 'form-control tinymce-editor'
        }).text(data[`${language}_${field.name}`] || '').appendTo(formGroup);

        // Initialize TinyMCE for this textarea
        setTimeout(() => {
        tinymce.init({
          selector: `#${textareaId}`,
          height: 300,
          license_key: 'gpl',
          menubar: true,
          plugins: [
              'advlist', 'autolink', 'lists', 'link', 'image', 'charmap', 'preview',
              'anchor', 'searchreplace', 'visualblocks', 'code', 'fullscreen',
              'insertdatetime', 'media', 'table', 'help', 'wordcount'
          ],
          toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks | ' +
            'bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
            'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
            'removeformat | help',
          content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }',
          init_instance_callback: function(editor) {
            editor.setContent(data[`${language}_${field.name}`] || '');
            console.log('Editor: ' + editor.id + ' is now initialized.');
          }
        }),5000});

        modalEditorIds.push(textareaId);

I tried everything I could by reading documentation and searching every other side, but I am still not getting the data results.
Any clue what I am doing wrong here?
